# "Create followup question" feature

Tags: feature-request

Triggered by [Handling creeping questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143764/handling-creeping-questions).

When a question morphs into something different, a "Create followup question" link would open a new question and copy the original question's tags (and optionally content).

The new and original questions would be linked, similar to duplicate question links.

This provides normalized ways for trails of questions which are inappropriate in a single question, or for when a question morphs so much that existing answers are no longer relevant. Followup questions could be asked by the original asker, a user <sup>(with enough rep?)</sup>, from a comment, or...

If a non-asker creates the followup the OP would be notified. Not sure about notifying OP respondents.

This would also provide a way for people to track the genesis of a solution, or to track back and forth if they're in a different stage of the same process.

Robert raises an important point–we can already insert links to/from OP/NP. This is occasionally done. The feature request is for a normalization/officialization of that process–to make it easier to connect narratives that *should* be connected. Other than providing a "de-followup" action I'm not sure how to police this functionality to avoid misuse/abuse yet.

Comment: It could (in some way) incorporate some features of the original as well to make life easier for the OP - eg automatically including tags.

Comment: I feel like this feature would be extremely confusing to new users and easily misunderstood.

Comment: @gobernador How so, and how could it be improved? By hiding it until you had a certain rep, or...?

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, by mis-used the first thing that comes to mind is a user post a "follow up" question to just some random question when they should have just started a brand new question.

Comment: I don't think that hiding it until you had a certain rep level would be a good thing, because I feel like it would most benefit inexperienced users.

Comment: @gobernador What are some potential solutions, then, if it's most confusing to those it would benefit most?

Comment: @Dave Honestly, I don't know. Your idea has merit, due to the iterative nature of problem-solving as you say, but I don't have a solution, only a concern.

Comment: "Not sure about notifying OP respondents." >> Nobody should have any right to notify any other user about a new question other than the user himself. Comments are already abused as a mechanism for simply getting somebody's attention; having automatic notifications would actually *encourage* that type of abuse. So no, absolutely freaking not, just because I answered somebody's question does not mean I have a duty to answer or even look at their follow-up questions; I did them one favour already.

Comment: @Aarobot I'm almost positive nobody believes you have a duty to answer or look at follow-up questions, but you sure seem mad.

Comment: The original comment that I replied to appears to have been deleted, but if I seem mad, it's only because I've been involved in these drawn-out threads before and can say with certainty that almost nobody, under any circumstances, would want to be notified about the follow-up questions; after a few rounds of this fix-it-for-me-I'm-helpless game, most people just want out.

Comment: @Aarobot Oh, I thought you were quoting the question, since that's what I said in the question. Being involved in a long, drawn-out thread implies you participated--that's voluntary, AFAIK :)

Comment: Sure, I participated, but it wasn't long and drawn-out when I started participating. It starts out as simply answering a question, then politely responding to a few quick follow-up comments, and eventually devolves into unpaid consulting services. That is, in my not inconsiderable experience, about the time when a follow-up question is most likely to be created - and not coincidentally the time when those helping with the original problem are least likely to want to continue the thread.

Comment: @Aarobot I guess I'd just say "don't continue it" then. IMO setting expectations is part of public discourse on a forum. I'm not fundamentally *disagreeing* with your concern, I just don't care about it ;)

Comment: WTF? I *don't* continue it, that's the whole point. Sending notifications about "follow-up" questions is telling them that they *should* continue it, creating noise in their inbox about questions and users they want nothing to do with anymore. Even *manual* notifications (where some user replies to an old answer of mine and writes "could you come answer my other question [link]") are seriously annoying; *automatic* notifications would most definitely turn people off of the site.

Comment: Simply, the ability to choose *which* questions to answer, and not be bothered about the ones they don't, is one of the principal reasons that good contributors don't burn out within a few weeks. And even then, as I mentioned above, there are avenues for abuse. Participation is voluntary, the system doesn't send notifications for things that users aren't reasonably expected to be interested in; if I'm still interested in the subject and following the site/tags, I'll see the follow up question anyway. If not, then I'm not interested.

Comment: @Aarobot I didn't not-understand what you said :) Heeding a notification is voluntary, actually; I have no issues ignoring a direct mention-for-help--YMMV. And no, it's not *should*, it's *may*. WTF yourself; if you're not capable of not answering someone or not clicking on a link, that's your problem, AFAIC. I *said* I understood your point, I just don't *agree* with it to the extent you do. I *said* it was undecided in my head, and it still is. It's not even the main point--I'd rather you focused on the overall functionality, not your issue with a single sentence.

Comment: I don't feel guilty about ignoring notifications. I'm saying that the notifications are noise. They're not telling the recipient anything that they've expressed even a tacit interest in. This would be like having a discussion forum automatically subscribe you to every forum or thread you post in, regardless of whether or not the replies are actually addressed to you. What you're proposing isn't a usability feature, it's just an annoyance.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the overall functionality. That's what votes, as opposed to comments, are for. I'm taking issue with a specific aspect of it, and if it's not even important to you then I don't see why you waste your time defending it.

Comment: What I *proposed* was a "create followup" link. There was a single sentence regarding whether or not original respondents should be notified, which I was clear I was uncertain about.

Comment: @Aarobot What I'm defending is the notion that you have any sort of obligation to respond to a notification, which you took two full comments to imply was simply an intolerable burden, which I think is funny. Reasonable people can disagree, I just don't understand the vitriol, and I'm done with it.

Comment: At no point did I say that there is any obligation. I'm not sure how you came to a misunderstanding of such magnitude. On the precise contrary, my objection to this is that it creates the *implication* or *perception* of some obligation where there is none. It further annoys people who are already annoyed and have been trying to help. And it does so with no likely benefit, since the follow-up question will either already be answered by the time the OP sees it (if it's a good question) or simply not answered at all (if it's as bad as the first). There's no reason to include that "feature" here.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure we want to encourage this.

I've seen community members who post a long string of simple questions that really would be better served by a book or tutorial.  They do this quite readily, without any prompting from a "follow-up" mechanism.

I'd prefer to ease the rules a bit so that people could post comprehensive answers to questions of a more general nature (as opposed to questions of a highly-localized troubleshooting nature), but the community seems so allergic to this type of contribution that I doubt it will ever get any traction.

Regardless, I think that posting strings of questions, whether they are related by some mechanism or not, is contrary to the current Stack Overflow ethos of "What have you tried," and "Show us the work you've done so far."  Instead of solving the problem one time via a comprehensive, well thought-out answer, it's death by a thousand pinpricks.

Comment: The nature of problem-solving is iterative, and solving one problem often leads to another, not-necessarily-related one. I don't think answers here lead themselves to comprehensive, all-encompassing answers, because solution to larger problems diverge *very* quickly, at least in the tags I tend to be in. I'm sympathetic to pinpricks, I'm just not sure the options are better (questions that completely change meaning, relying on manual linking, etc.)

Comment: But why do you need a new mechanism for this? What would you gain that isn't already adequately served by links provided by the OP?  In fact, this is precisely what you accomplished by the link you provided in your question here.

Comment: I don't think that this will be a problem. We already have the 6-per-day restriction, so the worst you'll get is 6 of them from a particular user. The main benefit of this question is that the follow-ups will automatically have a link to the prior question. Thus a clear chain can be determined.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because manual processes don't tend to work. I'm not sure how the feature would be policed to avoid inappropriate use yet other than providing a "Nuh-uh" action for people with edit access or something.

Comment: I don't think we should discourage features that could be quite useful, just because they could be mis-used by help vampires and such.

Comment: @AdamRackis: The possibility of abuse *always* has to be considered.  Were that not the case, we would have no need for rate limits and Captchas.

Comment: Rate limits and captchas are a *great* way to limit abuse.  They **keep** the features, and just (try to) make sure they're not abused.